# Issue requesting token from Sonos api in oauth process

Tags: oauth, sonos

**Problem**
I am trying to implement the  [Sonos Authorization API](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/) as I am trying to build a small IoT device I want to use as a remote but I am facing difficulties with the oauth process.

**I did the following**

1. Create a Sonos dev-account and create credentials
2. Open the "[Create Authorization Code](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/create-authorization-code/)" in the browser and enter my Sonos credentials. In this step I get redirected to the redirect url as expected (I used requestbin.com and postb.in to get started)
3. Try to [create the token](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/create-token/) but I get a client_invalid error which is supposed to mean the authorization code is incorrect

**What I noticed**
As I havent implemented any custom code yet I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I noticed the authorization codes I receive (e.g. ZGyr3PrM) are much shorter in comparison to the examples (e.g. f10072fa6-2134-4fe1-93fd-ca5b9cffa738).

Do you have any ideas how to fix this or did anyone else have the same issues?

Thanks for your support
Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

The example how to add the authorization in the [documentation to create the token](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/create-token/) ist not correct.

It should be

> Authorization: Basic {Base64 clientid:secret}

instead of

> Authorization: Basic {Base64 clientid and secret}

Comment: Thanks for that. I fixed the [Create Token](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/create-token/) doc. You can also see more details in the [Authorize](https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/authorize/) doc.